# Как изменить строку с заголовком приложения

Tags: android, android-menu

Не могу разобраться с тем как убрать логотип приложения из заголовка.
Кроме того, нужно ещё в одной из активити указать стрелку home.

Как просто указать стрелку понятно - с помощью метода `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`. Как убрать логотип понятно - `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`
Но как убрать логотип приложения так и отобразить стрелку - непонятно.
Если вызвать эти методы, то, в итоге, появляется ошибка:

```
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2131165184, size is 0
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.getItem(MenuBuilder.java:656)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.example.crazywheel.MasterViewActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MasterViewActivity.java:30)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:407)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:201)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-31 21:00:17.096: E/AndroidRuntime(3122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPD**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();    
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("My Profile");
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_master_view, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Стек вызовов не соответствует коду метода `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Ошибка, по-моему, из-за неправильного использования `MenuBuilder.getItem`. По стеку видно, что этот метод вызывался, а в коде его нет. Как так?

Answer (score 1):

только я использовал ActionBarSherlock и мне помогло так. (у меня был код в onCreate())

```
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ab.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Я прописал код в onCreateOptionsMenu и вот что получил:
![alt text][1]   

[1]: http://i33.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0203/2f/306fb4e674ac8d37c50a6f19af13542f.png

Comment: Как изменить цвет фона actionBar?

Comment: setTitle(""); // или через манифест
setTitleColor(textColor); // или лучше это сделать в styles

Comment: setTitleColor(textColor); - это же не цвет фона

Comment: да и если задать setTitle(""), то ни кнопки ни стрелки вообще

Answer (score 0):

`setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`

Comment: Это да, но как сделать так, чтобы логотипа не было, а кнопка home была?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13704953/remove-icon-but-have-homeasup-in-actionbar

Comment: На всех предложенных там вариантах происходит креш приложения..

Comment: Покажите содержимое `com.example.crazywheel.MasterViewActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: Добавил кода.    
Не пойму как в итоге должно быть. При всех конфигурациях из SO креш приложения

Comment: Можно ли вообще убрать логотип приложения?